# React Native remove Default launcher or splash screen in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, splash-screen, launch-screen

I am learning react native. When I create react native project, it automatically create a splash or launcher screen in IOS project. My requirement is, I don't want splash or launcher screen. In android, it is possible, but in case of IOS, I am not able to remove the default screen. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Go to iOS project settings and change there. Check **App Icons and Launch Images** section. If you want to add an image as launch screen change **Launch Images Source**. Or else if you have more functionality on launch screen then build custom UI using `LaunchScreen.Xib`

[image]

For more info: [How to add splash screen](https://medium.com/handlebar-labs/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-ios-and-android-30a3cec835ae)

Comment: Thankyou so much, for the quick response. Let me try your solution.

Comment: I want to remove the splash screen completely.

Comment: Whatever the screen you want to show first add that in Launch screen file

Comment: Otherwise go to  info.plist file in your project and you have the line "Launch screen interface file base name". remove it

Comment: Be aware that by removing completely, you may get compatible issues like  blank black space at the top or bottom of screen.

Comment: what is the solution for that black space on top and bottom?